# Exercise for office worker who spend most of the day sitting

Tags: weightlifting, body-fat, bodyweight-exercises

What kind of exercise is most beneficial, if I am spending most of my time sitting in the office?

I have been working out for quite some time, with 60% of my workout targeted on pectorals and thighs.

Now, things have changed  and I want to change my workout routine to suit my current lifestyle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spend most of my time at a computer, and consequently developed some *really* bad posture. What fixed it were a host of exercises that required **thoracic extension**, and compound movements that recruit multiple muscle groups simultaneously. Great options are:

1. **Conventional deadlift**: With proper form, (shoulder blades pulled back and low, neutral spine) I don't think that there is a faster way to fix "slumped shoulders."
2. **Bent over rows**: A similar idea, but get your back in check, so that everything starts to work properly again.
3. **Overhead press/ front squats** Help develop core stability, by forcing your body to keep balance. Esp. front squat, since the weight is displaced from your center of gravity, core strength and shoulder flexibility are essential if you want to keep good form and lift heavy weights.
4. **Pull ups**: I do pull ups absolutely every day, wider grip, chest flared a little bit, and keeping your core tight. Excellent exercise for overall development.

Good luck and happy lifting

Answer (score 2):

The most important exercise if you're sitting in the office all day is [regular short walks on the hour](http://www.mensjournal.com/health-fitness/exercise/a-five-minute-walk-could-undo-an-hour-of-sitting-20141009). Sitting has been shown to have negative effects on circulation in the legs [which has a subsequent effect on mortality](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifestyle/why-sitting-is-killing-you.html), but a short walk seems to solve the problem entirely. I've seen suggestions of 10 minutes every six hours, 5 minutes every hour... I personally just take a quick circuit of the office, generally refilling my coffee cup or water bottle at the same time so that I look busy.

Comment: yeah I tend to fill up my glass of water only part way so that I can get up and fill it again in not too long.